# Using sigprocmask and sigsuspend to bounce signal between two processes

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm learning Operating system fundamentals and got this idea I want to implement: I want to create one parent and one child processes. These two processes will bounce signal between each other for N times. The way I was thinking of it is a kid and parent playing ball with each other. I want to use SIGUSR1 as the "ball" to send between them. I used sigsuspend() and sigprocmask() so that each process will wait for the signal from the other process, before sending the signal back. However, I'm not sure if I implemented the sigsuspend and sigprocmask correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
//playing ball with one parent and child process for N times 
int N= atoi (argv[1]);
pid_t child_pid;
pid_t vfork(void);
sigset_t newmask, waitmask;

child_pid = vfork();

sigemptyset(&waitmask); 
sigemptyset(&newmask); 
sigaddset(&waitmask, SIG_BLOCK); 
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);

 if(child_pid < 0){
   return 1; 
 }
while(N !=0){
  if(child_pid == 0){
  //the child has the ball and will throw it to the parent
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &waitmask);
  sigsuspend(&waitmask);
  printf("Hey parent throw the ball\n"); 
  sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &newmask, NULL); 
  kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1); 
  printf("Hey parent catch the ball\n");
  N--; 

  }
  else{
  //parent has the ball and will throw it to the child 
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &waitmask);//parent waits for the child to throw ball 
  sigsuspend(&waitmask);
  printf("Hey child throw the ball\n"); 
  sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &newmask, NULL);   
  kill(child_pid, SIGUSR1); 
  printf("Hey kid catch the ball\n"); 
  N--; 
  }
}

}
```

The additional libraries are for other functions system calls I want to later use after being able to run this one properly. I used vfork() instead of fork() cause I read that the parent process will remain suspended till the child process completes its execution.
Updated code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
//ps aux | awk {'print $8'}|grep -c Z
void handler(int signum){} //CHANGE HERE 
int main(int argc, char** argv){
//playing ball with one parent and child process for N times 
int N= atoi (argv[1]);
pid_t child_pid;
sigset_t newmask, waitmask;
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &waitmask); 
child_pid = fork();

sigemptyset(&waitmask); 
sigemptyset(&newmask); 
sigaddset(&waitmask, SIG_BLOCK); 
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);

 if(child_pid < 0){
   return 1; 
 }
 while (N--) //NEW CHANGE HERE 
    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
      printf("Hey, parent, throw the ball!\n");
      sigsuspend(&waitmask);
      // the child has the ball and will throw it to the parent
     
      printf("Hey, parent, catch the ball!\n");
      kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    }
    
    else
    {
      // parent has the ball and will throw it to the child
      signal(SIGUSR1, handler); // CHANGE HERE 
      printf("Hey, kid, catch the ball!\n");
      kill(child_pid, SIGUSR1);
      printf("Hey, child, throw the ball!\n");
      sigsuspend(&waitmask);
    }

}
```

Output image when tested with N = 4
[./catch 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evZSi.png)

Comment: "I used vfork() instead of fork() cause I read that the parent process will remain suspended till the child process completes its execution."  But that's the exact opposite of what you want.  For this to work, the parent needs to be able to run while the child is alive (and waiting for the signal).  You really do just want fork.  There are basically no appropriate uses for vfork in this day and age.

Comment: I see, I didnt consider that - I changed it to fork( ) thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I used sigsuspend() and sigprocmask() so that each process will wait for the signal from the other process, before sending the signal back.

- Understandably since each process waits before sending, nothing happens, and that's exactly how the program behaves; the comments `the child has the ball and will throw it to the parent` and `parent has the ball and will throw it to the child` are untrue. You have to decide one process to send before waiting, e. g. the parent.
- You must install a signal handler (which can be as simple as `void handler(int signum) {}`) for the *ball*, otherwise it kills the poor process which wants to catch it: `signal(SIGUSR1, handler);`
- The `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &waitmask)` must be called before the `fork()`, otherwise the signal could be delivered before a process waits for it, and the later waiting would last forever. For the same reason, `sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &newmask, NULL)` must not be called. So, the loop can become:

  ```
    while (N--)
      if (child_pid == 0)
      {
        printf("Hey, parent, throw the ball!\n");
        sigsuspend(&waitmask);
        // the child has the ball and will throw it to the parent
        printf("Hey, parent, catch the ball!\n");
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
      }
      else
      {
        // parent has the ball and will throw it to the child
        printf("Hey, kid, catch the ball!\n");
        kill(child_pid, SIGUSR1);
        printf("Hey, child, throw the ball!\n");
        sigsuspend(&waitmask);
      }
  ```

Comment: I added in the signal handler and put the `signal(SIGUSR1, handler);`  in the `else` section. I also used your code for the while loop as well to see what happens - I tested `./catch 4` and the out put was : 
`Hey, kid, catch the ball!`
`Hey, child, throw the ball!`
And then it seems to be stuck 
I'm using repl.it to test the code

Comment: The _`else` section_ (whatever that may be, since there is no other `else`) is not the right place for _the `signal(SIGUSR1, handler);`_ - the handler must have been installed for parent and child.